# How to move or copy sheets starting with same name from multiple workbooks in one a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 excel workbooks each containing 35 sheets.
Each workbook have one sheet where, the first there character of the sheet name is same in all the workbooks .
For example:
tes_8,tes_9,tes_3,tes_2 are sheet names in workbook1,workbook2,workbook3 and workbook4 respectively.

Now I want to copy sheets with sheet name having the first three character same from these four workbooks into a single workbook , so here I want a new excel workbook containing these four sheets: tes_8,tes_9 tes_3,tes_2

I was attempting to do this manually i.e.
by right clicking on the sheet then ,select move or copy option then ,check the create a copy checkbox and then select the workbook you want your sheet to move to.
Since there are 35 sheets moving manually is taking a lot of time.

Comment: Please don't write in all upper-case, it's considered shouting, and it's rather rude to should at the people you ask for help. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the suggestion! I will keep  this in  mind and try to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below example code:

```
Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("Destination workbook location")

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    
select case left(Worksheets(i).Name,5) '' As your sheet name is 5 letters (tes_8,tes_9)
        
case tes_8,tes_9 tes_3,tes_2     '' checking whether it is in the start of sheet names
         
worksheets(i).Copy Before:=closedBook.Sheets(1)   '' copy those sheets to destination workbook
         
closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
end select

Next i
```

I'm new in this community. I hope you can use it to create a vba program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the solution.  Can you please explain ,where to write this code .

Comment: Dear, I would love to help you more. unfortunately I have limited access to system and will take more time to give you a perfect program. You can use the above for loop to copy selected sheet to another workbook

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheets That Start With... to New Workbook

- In all (source) workbooks from the list (adjust), it will locate the first worksheet whose name starts with `tes_` (adjust) and copy it to a new (destination) workbook.
- If a source workbook is open it will leave it open, if not, using the path `C:\Test` (adjust), it will open it and close it after copying the worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyWorksheets()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const swbNamesList As String = "wb1.xlsx,wb2.xlsx,wb3.xlsx,wb4.xlsx"
    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const swsNameLeft As String = "tes_"
    
    ' Determine and validate the source path ('sPath').
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory)
    If Len(sPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & sFolderPath & "' was not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    sPath = sFolderPath
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        sPath = sPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    
    ' Write the source workbook names from the list to an array ('swbNames').
    Dim swbNames() As String: swbNames = Split(swbNamesList, ",")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declare variables used for the first time
    ' in the following For...Next loop.
    Dim swb As Workbook ' Current Source Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet ' Current Source Worksheet
    Dim swbPath As String ' Current Source Path
    Dim swbWasClosed As Boolean ' Closed Boolean
    Dim dwb As Workbook ' Destination Workbook
    Dim dwsCount As Long ' Destination Worksheets Count
    Dim n As Long ' Source Workbook Names Counter
    
    ' Loop through the elements of the array.
    For n = 0 To UBound(swbNames)
        ' Attempt to reference the source workbook.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set swb = Workbooks(swbNames(n))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If swb Is Nothing Then ' the source workbook is not open
            ' Attempt to open the source workbook.
            swbPath = sPath & swbNames(n)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath)
            On Error GoTo 0
            swbWasClosed = True
        'Else ' the source workbook is open
        End If
        If Not swb Is Nothing Then ' the source workbook is open
            For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
                If InStr(1, sws.Name, swsNameLeft, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    If dwsCount = 0 Then
                        sws.Copy ' creates a new single-worksheet workbook
                        Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count) ' reference it
                    Else
                        sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
                    End If
                    dwsCount = dwsCount + 1
                    Exit For ' stop looping because the worksheet was found
                'Else ' not a match; do nothing
                End If
            Next sws
            If swbWasClosed Then ' the source workbook was closed
                swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                swbWasClosed = False ' reset the variable
            'Else ' the source workbook was open, let it be; do nothing
            End If
            Set swb = Nothing ' reset the variable
        'Else ' the source file (workbook) doesn't exist; do nothing
        End If
    Next n

    If dwsCount > 0 Then dwb.Saved = True ' just for easy closing while testing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    Select Case dwsCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "No worksheets found.", vbCritical
    Case 1
        MsgBox "Only one worksheet found.", vbExclamation
    Case n
        MsgBox "All " & n & " worksheets found.", vbInformation
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Only " & dwsCount & " worksheets found.", vbExclamation
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!! . I am able to get the desired output from this code.